# How to validate object is an array and not empty in Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am trying to create the following object test:

1. validate if an object is an array
2. validate if this array is not empty

In Chai, that would be:

```
expect(response['output']['data']['results']).to.be.an('array').not.empty;
```

But in Jest I wrote:

```
expect(Array.isArray(response['output']['data']['results'])).toBe(true);
expect(response['output']['data']['results'].length > 0).toBe(true);
```

Is there a cleaner approach available in Jest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to create the following object test:
>
> 1. validate if an object is an array
> 2. validate if this array is not empty

So (with only [Jest's built-in expectations](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect)):

```js
expect(thing).toBeInstanceOf(Array);
          // ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1. is an array
expect(thing).not.toHaveLength(0);
          // ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 2. is not empty
```

Running through some examples:

```js
[
    "foo",
    {},
    [],
    ["foo"],
    ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
].forEach((thing) => {
    it(`tests ${JSON.stringify(thing)}`, () => {
        expect(thing).toBeInstanceOf(Array);
        expect(thing).not.toHaveLength(0);
    });
});
```

gives the expected result:

```
 FAIL  src/non-empty-array.spec.ts
  ✕ tests "foo" (1 ms)
  ✕ tests {}
  ✕ tests [] (1 ms)
  ✓ tests ["foo"] (1 ms)
  ✓ tests ["foo","bar","baz"]
```

with useful failures:

- Tells you if it's primitive:

  ```
    ● tests "foo"

      expect(received).toBeInstanceOf(expected)

      Expected constructor: Array

      Received value has no prototype
      Received value: "foo"
  ```
- Tells you if it's an instance of something else:

  ```
    ● tests {}

      expect(received).toBeInstanceOf(expected)

      Expected constructor: Array
      Received constructor: Object
  ```
- Tells you if it's empty:

  ```
    ● tests []

      expect(received).not.toHaveLength(expected)

      Expected length: not 0
      Received array:      []
  ```

---

When you flatten all expectations down to `expect(someBool).toBe(true)` you lose any useful diagnostic information; *every single one* of those failing cases with your original attempt gives:

```
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false
```

and which specific line it failed on is the only useful part of the output.

---

Testing out [Lin Du's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76233200/3001761):

- `.toBeArrayOfSize` requires you to specify the exact length. I did also try `expect(thing).toBeArrayOfSize(expect.toBePositive())`, but the asymmetric matcher isn't applied correctly:

  ```
      expect(received).toBeArrayOfSize(expected)

      Expected value to be an array of size:
        toBePositive<>
      Received:
        value: ["foo"]
        length: 1
  ```

  and `.not.toBeArrayOfSize(0)`, but it won't fail for the string and object cases, only for the `[]` case.
- `.toSatisfy` does show you what value failed to satisfy the expectation, but nothing more than that:

  ```
      expect(received).toSatisfy()

      Expected value to satisfy:
        [Function anonymous]
      Received:
        []
  ```

---

Testing out [Teneff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76234164/3001761) with:

```js
expect({ thing }).toHaveProperty("thing", expect.arrayContaining([expect.anything()]));
```

you just see the mismatching property's value, e.g.:

```
    expect(received).toHaveProperty(path, value)

    Expected path: "thing"

    Expected value: ArrayContaining [Anything]
    Received value: []
```

But if it can't follow the whole path, it shows you more context of the object as needed:

```
    expect(received).toHaveProperty(path, value)

    Expected path: "foo.bar"
    Received path: []

    Expected value: ArrayContaining [Anything]
    Received value: {"thing": []}
```

For cases like yours where the array's in a nested object, this is very helpful.

I don't think *"it's a single assertion (otherwise if the first fails, the error for the second won't be displayed)"* is particularly useful here - if it's *not* an array, then continuing on and asserting on its length property doesn't make much sense.

---

I also tried to see what [`jest-codemods`](https://github.com/skovhus/jest-codemods) would recommend if you asked it to migrate you from Chai BDD to Jest, but that wasn't much help:

```
expect(thing).toEqual([])
```

---

For completion's sake note that, if you really want, you can *use Chai*. Jest will fail the test if an error is thrown; it doesn't care whether that's by the implementation, its own expectations or Chai's. That said, the message on failure can be a little confusing:

```
    Expected value not be strictly equal to:
      undefined
    Received:
      []
    
    Message:
      expected [] not to be empty

    Difference:

      Comparing two different types of values. Expected undefined but received array.
```

This is due to the the properties set on the Chai error object - `actual` and `message` are provided, so Jest shows them, but (as it's not a direct comparison) `expected` isn't. That means it can't show a useful difference.

Comment: You do see the entire "received data", in case the received data is an empty array - you do see it in the output, which I think is useful, especially in CI for long-running tests

Comment: @teneff it shows the whole _array_, or whatever else the value at that path turned out to be, but not the whole _object_ it was part of. IIRC it only shows the object if the path doesn't exist in it (e.g. `expect({ thing }).toHaveProperty("foo", ...)` would show the whole object). But rereading I think that's what you meant, I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to test it like this

```js
it('should have nested property output.data.results, which is an array containing anything', () => {
  expect(response).toHaveProperty('output.data.results', expect.arrayContaining([
    expect.anything()
  ]))    
})
```

The advantages are:

- it's a single assertion (otherwise if the first fails, the error for the second won't be displayed)
- the entire `result` is passed to the `expect()` function, so in case some of the nested properties are missing - the entire object will be displayed in the error

[working example](https://replit.com/@StefanTeneff/jest-playground-7#sum.test.js)

---

[Here](https://replit.com/@StefanTeneff/so-76233061#response.test.js) you can see different examples of how the failures will be represented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.toBeArrayOfSize()`](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/matchers/array/#tobearrayofsize) or [`.toSatisfy(predicate)`](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/matchers/tosatisfy) from `jest-extended`

> `jest-extended` aims to add additional matchers to Jest's default ones making it easy to test everything

Example:

```js
describe('76233061', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const response = {
      output: {
        data: {
          results: [1]
        }
      }
    }
    expect(response.output.data.results).toSatisfy((x) => Array.isArray(x) && x.length > 0);
    expect(response.output.data.results).toBeArrayOfSize(1);
  })
})
```

Comment: `toSatisfy` is not a good way to get useful diagnostics on failure - in your example you wouldn't know which condition wasn't met.

Comment: How would you modify this Jest expect replacing `toSatisfy`? TY